# How to limit data type to 6 digit numbers in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, integer, constraints, create-table

I have a table in sql for a bank account

```
CREATE TABLE (
    name VARCHAR(100),
    bsb INTEGER,
    account_num INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (bsb, account_num)
);
```

How do I put a constraint that will limit BSB to only integers that have 6 digits including 000,000 all the way to 999,999? Do I need a constraint or to use a different data type?

I know I can do this check restraint to limit the size of an int to be 6 digits `CONSTRAINT Bank_BSB_CHK CHECK (BSB < 999999)` but a BSB can start with 0's but just has to be 6 digits long.

Comment: Are you saying you want bsb to be 000000 for 0? I'm not sure that has any meaning with integers. Wouldn't varchar(6) be better for that?

Comment: If you want leading zero's, I'd use a char data type. (constraint to make sure length 6 and only digits.)

Comment: I 'd put a constraint < 999999 and let the front end take core of adding leading `0`s if missing to make sure you have 6 digits. Or use `char` data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is a sequence of 6 digits with no mathematical meaning it is better to use a `CHAR(6)` data type and put a constraint on the pattern the `bsb` can take. This would be the correct constraint to limit the pattern to 6 digits.

```
CONSTRAINT Bank_Account_BSB_CHK CHECK (bsb SIMILAR TO '[[:digit:]]{6}')
```

Comment: It works in PostgreSQL of which the question tagged as

Answer (score 4):

An integer has no fixed format, so `000001` and `1` are the same value. So if you really want an integer, then the correct constraint is `CHECK (BSB >= 0 AND BSB <= 999999)` (note that you had a fence-post error in your question, using `<` not `<=`).

If your data is actually a sequence of 6 digits, with no mathematical meaning, like a phone number, you're probably better off using a string data type, and constraining it by pattern. That way, you won't have to worry about reformatting it when displaying the data.

A reasonably portable constraint would be to use the `SIMILAR TO` operator (I don't know how widely implemented it is, but it is apparently in the SQL standard), which uses a regular expression:

```
CHECK ( BSB SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{6}' )
```